# Read More | Duplicating characters

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to add read more / less paragraph. Its working fine but duplicating the word eg. **management** breaks into **manag** & **gement** resulting spelling mistake.Check screenshot.

```
var showChar = 370;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $("p", this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

            $("p", this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Use `showChar` instead of `showChar-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) bug (also called off-by-one error).

Replace

```
content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);
```

with

```
content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
```